# How to access a widget in another widget event handler : Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, reference, global-variables

I am creating a GUI in tkinter having a `listbox` and a `Text` item in a child window which appears after a button click. `Listbox` is displaying values of a `dict` which are basically names of files/directories in disk image.
I want to change the text of `Text` widget on `<ListboxSelect>` event and display type or path of selected file.

Now I cant make `Text` global since it has to appear on child window, so I need a way to access it in event handler of `Listbox`. Can I give handler reference of `Textbox`?

Here is my code;

```
def command(event):
    ...          #Need to change the Text here, how to access it?

def display_info(dict,filename):
    child_w = Tk()
    listbox = Listbox(child_w)
    textview = Text(child_w)

    ...

    listbox.bind(<ListboxSelect>,command)

def upload_file():



window = Tk()
upl_button = Button(command=upload_file)

window.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to create a textview as global and then change its properties later to be displayed in child_window etc.

Comment: Several instances of `tk.Tk()` is a bad idea - use `tk.Toplevel` instead. Also post an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can make the Text instance global. There's nothing about the child window that would prevent that.

Comment: @Novel Can I create textview as global without declaring it child of child_w as child_w is dependent on upl_Button? I mean I have to add parent in its constructor?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I have uploaded the mvce already. Its just two windows. Thanks for the suggestion of using Toplevel.

Comment: You can just make it global or pass it as a argument to the callback event

Comment: @aneela Your code is minimal, but not complete. I can't run that to test it. Show us a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions here that I can think of is to make `textview` a globalized variable or to pass `textview` to `command()` as an argument.

- Parameter solution:

```
def command(event,txtbox):
    txtbox.delete(...)

def display_info(dict,filename):
    child_w = Tk()
    listbox = Listbox(child_w)
    textview = Text(child_w)

    ...

    listbox.bind('<ListboxSelect>',lambda event: command(event,textview))
```

- Or simply just globalize it:

```
def command(event):
    textview.delete(...)

def display_info(dict,filename):
    global textview

    child_w = Tk()
    listbox = Listbox(child_w)
    textview = Text(child_w)

    ...

    listbox.bind('<ListboxSelect>',command)
```

While saying all this, it is good to keep in mind that creating more than one instance of `Tk` is almost never a good idea. Read: [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)